# Split sentence into bits like this .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, split

i need to split this text

> This is really cool, and i like it.

into this

```
this
is
really
cool
,
and
i
like
it
.
```

Any idea how to do this? splitting with space give this

```
this
is
really
cool,
and
i
like
it.
```

i need the punctuation i a separate element of an array

thanks

Comment: What should happen to "OK... Here's Mr. Smith's C.V."?

Comment: is the delim here the "," ..? simplist way to do it just glancing at it would be var x = "This is really cool, and I like it."; var y=x.Replace(",", " "); then do a split on the spaces and replace the space after the word cool with "," of course you can do linq or use a for loop to check and replace

Comment: @MarkByers each letter (in the case of C.V.), and punctuation would be in an element on the array.

Comment: @DJKRAZE the Delimiter i used here is Space, but i don't know if i split with character array what the output would be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use String.Split to split on "nothing".

Instead, you could use `Regex.Split` to do this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[ ]|(?=[,.])");
string[] items = r.Split(input);
```

In this pattern, we either match a space (which gets "consumed"), OR, we do a look-ahead for punctuation (and don't "consume" it).

Comment: thanks you very much, is it possible you could explain the Regex pattern to me?

Comment: `@"[\s]|(?=\p{P})"` would extend it to other punctuation characters, and to whitespace other than space.

Answer (score 2):

If all you care about is the output and you're not extremely concerned about performance, why not do something like this:

```
string[] splitSentence(string sentence) {
    return sentence
        .Replace(",", " , ")
        .Replace(".", " . ")
        .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

It'll work! :)  Of course if you *do* care about performance, see Scott's answer.

Comment: Keep-it-simple ... I agree.  Regex sometimes provides "cool" solutions, but complexity grows exponentially.  This is a good solution.

Comment: Also, Regex takes much more processing than simple string manipulations, so I really couldn't say which method is faster.

Comment: Agreed, this is certainly something that should be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably approach this one the old fashioned way and simply iterate over each character. Something like:

```
    static private IList<string> SplitString(string str)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i]))
            {
                // split silently at whitespace
                if (line.Length > 0)
                    lines.Add(line.ToString());
                line.Clear();
            }
            else if (IsPunctuationCharacter(str[i]))
            {
                // split for punctuation and include each punctuation character as its own line
                if (line.Length > 0)
                    lines.Add(line.ToString());
                lines.Add(new string(new char[] { str[i] }));
                line.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                // all other characters get added to the current line
                line.Append(str[i]);
            }
        }

        if (line.Length > 0)
            lines.Add(line.ToString());

        return lines;
    }

    static private bool IsPunctuationCharacter(char c)
    {
        if (c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```